# Unicode latin1 string encode / decode

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding

While fetching data from an unknown/old/non-consistent Mysql database to a Postgres utf-8 db using Python (Django) ORM I have sometimes faulty encoded data as a result.

Target: **grégory**

```
> a
u'gr\xe3\xa9gory'

> print a
grã©gory
```

I tried several decode/encode tricks without success:

```
 > print a.encode('utf-8').decode('latin1')
 grÃ£Â©gory

 > print a.encode('utf-8').decode('latin1')
 grÃ£Â©gory

 > print a.decode('latin-1')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 2-3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Even with some
unicode_escape

Comment: How are you fetching the data? You've got a unicode instance there with the wrong characters in it; you want to fix the decoding step that produced `a` in the first place. The code you're showing is happening too late.

Comment: The data, even if interpreted as bytes instead of unicode, is not valid UTF8. E3 A9 is not ever encountered in that encoding.

Comment: [This](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) should help you with unicode in python 2.x; it's the "unicode sandwich" talk.

Comment: What is the correct Unicode codepoint for those two bytes? We can probably figure out what went wrong here but without knowing what the *correct* interpretation would be it's almost impossible to reconstruct.

Comment: Last but not least, *encoding* to Latin-1 would at least preserve the 'bytes'; unicode code points 0-255 are encoded to bytes with matching values, so you can then re-interpret those bytes as a different encoding instead.

Comment: Also, if possible you should provide more examples...to see if there's a pattern in the faulty output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess the string has been incorrectly converted to lowercase at some point, changing `\xc3` to `\xe3`. The lowercase conversion has assumed latin1 encoding when it was actually utf-8.

```
>>> print 'gr\xc3\xa9gory'.decode('utf8')
grégory
```

Comment: Indeed, I do a lower() on the fetched string. I will try to fix the encoding/decoding at the insert level when reading from Mysql. Thanks !

Comment: @coulix: that was a crucial detail there; why lowercase broken data before repairing first?

Answer (score -1):

Since the problem was the lower(), I could fix it doing:

```
print a.upper().encode('latin1').lower()
```

Comment: No, `'Abcd'.lower().upper()` is not the same thing as `'Abcd'`. The OP should not lowercase the data before fixing it in the first place.

Comment: And to make this more explicit: There are plenty of partial UTF-8 bytes that could be interpreted as Latin-1 *lowercase* characters, and uppercase those is going to break *those* bytes instead. Calling `.upper()` will only introduce *more* errors.

Answer (score -6):

Try this:

```
print a.decode('latin1')
```

Comment: how should this be helpful?

Comment: `a` is a *`unicode`* object; calling `.decode()` implies there was an `.encode()` *first*. What should the data be encoded *to* in that case? Python will default to ASCII, and that'll fail for the E3 and A9 bytes.